# $\frac{dy}{dx} + Py = Q , y(x_0) = y_0$ has a unique solution if $P, Q$ are continuous on $\mathbb R$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to prove that $\frac{dy}{dx} + Py = Q , y(x_0) = y_0$  has a unique solution if $P, Q$  are continuous on $\mathbb R$.

**My attempt:** We know the general solution to it will be $y = e^{- \int P dx}\{C+ \int {Q e ^ {\int P dx}}\}$. Now as $P , Q$ are continuous on $\mathbb R$ , there will be antiderivative of them and $\int P dx$  and $\int (Q {\int P dx}) dx$  will be unique.

Have I gone wrong anywhere ? Can anyone please tell me ?

Comment: No antiderivative is unique... you have to use your initial value.

Comment: I think saying "the general solution is [whatever]" is assuming what you are trying to prove.

Comment: You can use the constant variation method to get uniqueness. Unlike what many people think, this is a method that allows to find all solutions to a linear equation (rather than only finding a particular solution). It can consequently be used to set up a proof that there is a unique solution to the Cauchy problem you are considering.

Comment: As ancientmathematician says, you cannot simply assume that every solution has this form. Doing so is assuming the thing you are trying to prove. Either show step-by-step that every solution must be in that form, or else show that if $y_1$ and $y_2$ are two solutions, then $y_1 - y_2$ must be $0$ (in particular, it solves a related differential equation where it is much easier to show that the only solution is $0$). But as svelaz points out, your claim of uniqueness for $\int P\,dx, \int Qe^{\int P,dx}\,dx$ is well-known to be false.